# if system date changes, how to prevent user change date of application in android?

Tags: android, datetime

In an Android offline application , i have been stuck in to an issue that.

if user changes the system date of android tablet/device than user is able to make some fake entries past dates.

i have tried to restrict user up to one week by taking last sync time and current time i.e user can very date for one week from current system date but if **system date changes** than my scenario does not work for past days.

Comment: Will it help if you don't allow new entries to be older than the latest entry?

Comment: yes, it will help. can you elaborate ?

Comment: Basically when an user makes an entry you just check the date and compare it to the maximum value of existing entries and allow saving only if the new entry is bigger than the current maximum.

Comment: okay got it. taking entry apart , is there any other way to do that user is unable to change application date just like wtsapp.

Comment: Do you need to prevent the date and time for being changed? Or any secure way to save current date and time, even offline? If your case is the second, I have asked a new question in hope to find a answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/47265996/3424212